# How does this variable passed into template in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

The view function looks like this:

```
def stats(request):
    """the stats page"""
    sidebarURLs = [reverse(p) for p in _sidebarPages]
    sidebar = zip(_sidebarPages, sidebarURLs, _sidebarNames)
    currpage = "dcstats"
    return render_to_response('datacollection/dcstats.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template file is like this:

```
{% extends "datacollection/login_base.html" %}
{% load dc_extras %}

{% block title %} {% endblock %}
{% block include %}

{% endblock %}

{% block onload %}
onload="init();"
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
      <nav>
     <ul>
        {% for pg, url, name in sidebar  %}
        {% ifequal currpage pg %}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
        {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
     </ul>
      </nav>
      {% if user.is_staff %}
          <p> {{ user.is_staff }}  </p>
  <nav>
     <h3>Admin:</h3>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="{% url report %}">Weekly Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url weekly_papers %}">Weekly Papers</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url weekly_datasets %}">Weekly Datasets</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url admin %}">Admin</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url teams %}">Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url submissions_admin %}">Paper Submissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url admin_help %}">Help</a></li>
 </ul>
  </nav>
      {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

What I don't understand is the variable `user` at the last of the template file, it cannot be found in the view function `stats`, how can it be passed into the template? Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks

Comment: because you works with `locals` it seems you should declare  `user` as local: `myUser = request.user`

Comment: @danihp Thanks! But I'm still not very clear about this. Is there a document about this?

Answer (score 3):

It is passed because you are using `RequestContext()` to pass some default context variables.
One of them is `user` passed by [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth).

`RequestContext()` is used, passes some default context variables.

More details of [Requestcontext is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).